# Construct a Binary Search Tree from given postorder

Tags: binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, postorder

there is any special method to do that? (not code method, like method in the head)

for example, this is postorder of the tree: 1 4 3 2 5 7 8 9 6 10

how can I know how to construct the tree?

thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing full binary tree given only postorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971981/constructing-full-binary-tree-given-only-postorder)

Comment: no, there are many things I didn't learn yet